# How to calculate values during object construction

Tags: c#

I have the following as a method to display

```
Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t\tPlayer Game Time: " + "\t{0} hours", playerGameTime);
Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t\tPlayer Money Spent: " + "\t{0} euros", playerMoneySpent);
```

This is what is stored in a `players[]` with `("Character Name", Wealth, Game Time, Money Spent)`

```
players[0] = new Player("John", 1000, 3, 0);
players[1] = new Player("James", 500, 6, 0);
```

Where do I do the calculation so that I can have Game Time * 0.5 and store it in the players[] instead of just 0.

I have initialized, get set and constructors set up.

Edit to add more info:

```
private int playerGameTime;
private double playerMoneySpent;

public int PlayerGameTime
{
     get { return playerGameTime; }
     set { playerGameTime = value; }
}

public double PlayerMoneySpent
{
     get { return playerMoneySpent; }
     set { playerMoneySpent = value; }
}

public Player(int _playerGameTime, double _playerMoneySpent)
{
     playerGameTime = _playerGameTime;
     playerMoneySpent = _playerMoneySpent;
}
```

Comment: Hi @BbOii and welcom to stackoverflow. Could you please add slightly more details like how the class Player looks like?

Comment: @JustShadow post edited for Player class info

Comment: I'd suggest you read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-properties

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is a calculated getter:

```
public double GameTime {
   get{
      return this.PlayerGameTime * 0.5;
   }

}
```

Comment: Typo: either `return this.PlayerGameTime / 2;` or `public double GameTime {...}`

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly you want to store **Game item * 0.5** in the **money spent** attribute. One way of doing this is in the constructor.

Bit of pseudo code here:

```cs
public Player ( String, String , int , int ){

// Initialisation of parameters 
this.MoneySpent = GameTime * 0.5

}
```

Or you do the calculation when instantiating the object.

Again some psuedo code here:

```cs
players[0] = new Player ("" , "", 6, 6 * 0.5);
```

There are loads of options. Really depends on the context of what you want to achieve.

Comment: This though means that if someone changes `GameTime`, which they can because they're public getters, `MoneySpent` is wrong.

Comment: That's why you have these setters so you can recalculate the moneyspent when gametime is set

Comment: That adds unnecessary side effects to what should be a simple operation. Calculated fields are much more declarative.

Comment: Even still since everything is public the value can never be fully trusted. Note also its just one way of doing things. I am not claiming its the best way.

Comment: *since everything is public the value can never be fully trusted* that doesn't make a lot of sense. Of course, you can "trust" public properties. It's just a property that's public...What makes you think you can't? even in a multi-threaded environment a public string is atomic so you can only ever get one value at a time from it.